# Response body empty even when caching enabled

Tags: java, spring, filter, response

Cannot get response body in my filter. Caching enabled.

I have tried many filter implementations - Filter, OncePerRequestFilter and GenericFilterBean. I have also tried writing custom caching mechanism but non of that work. I have already one logging filter working - this filter is executed before the new one and serves for reading request and response. The logging filter works but I want to add another one which reads response and validate it against XSD. Problem is, that logging filter gets the response filled OK but the XML validator filter gets empty string.

My @Controller method just returns Callable. Asynchronous processing may not be problem tho because logger filter works well.

```
@Component
public class ResposeBodyXmlValidator extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private final XmlUtils xmlUtils;
    private final Resource xsdResource;

    public ResposeBodyXmlValidator(
        XmlUtils xmlUtils,
        @Value("classpath:xsd/some.xsd") Resource xsdResource
    ) {
        this.xmlUtils = xmlUtils;
        this.xsdResource = xsdResource;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain
    ) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ContentCachingResponseWrapper response = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(httpServletResponse);

        doFilter(httpServletRequest, response, filterChain);

        if (MediaType.APPLICATION_XML.getType().equals(response.getContentType())) {
            try {
                xmlUtils.validate(new String(response.getContentAsByteArray(), response.getCharacterEncoding()), xsdResource.getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException | SAXException e) {
                String exceptionString = String.format("Chyba při volání %s\nNevalidní výstupní XML: %s",
                    httpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr(),
                    e.getMessage());
                response.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE + "; charset=UTF-8");
                response.setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
                response.getWriter().print(exceptionString);
            }
        }
        response.copyBodyToResponse(); // I found this needs to be added at the end of the filter
    }
}
```

I expect all my filters to be able to read response body which is cached.

**Update**

I was mistaken myself. Even LoggerFilter cannot read seponse. I think this has something to do with asynchronous processing of a request.